# jQuery css() not working in if statement

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, image

I have an if statement that checks to see if an image displayed in the DOM was originally smaller than 600px wide, and if it was, the image is resized to a different width. However it's not working. The correct value is displayed in the alert but doesn't get passed to the CSS a line below. Any idea why this could be happening?

jQuery

```
$('span.i_contact').each(function() {    
var imgWidth = parseInt($(this).data('image-width'));    
console.log(imgWidth)
if (imgWidth < 600) {
    var newWidth = ((imgWidth / 600) * 300)  
    alert(newWidth)
    $(this).css({
        "width":newWidth
    })    
}    
    var pos_width = ($(this).data('posWidth')) / 2.025;
    var pos_height = ($(this).data('posHeight')) / 2.025;
    var xpos = ($(this).data('posX')) / 2.025;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('posY')) / 2.025;
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid orange",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos
    }); 
var n = $(this).data('index');
$('.i_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode);   
});

$("span.o_contact").each(function() {        
var imgWidth = parseInt($(this).data('image-width'));
console.log(imgWidth)
if (imgWidth < 600) {
    var newWidth = ((imgWidth / 600) * 300);
    alert(newWidth)
    $(this).css({
        "width":newWidth
    });    
}    
    var pos_width = ($(this).data('posWidth')) / 2.025;
    var pos_height = ($(this).data('posHeight')) / 2.025;
    var xpos = ($(this).data('posX')) / 2.025;
    var ypos = ($(this).data('posY')) / 2.025;
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid green",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos  
    });
var n = $(this).data('index');
$(this).append(taggedNode);       
});
```

ERB (how the images are generated)

```
<% n = steps.index(step) %>
<h2 style="margin-left:20px;"> Step <%= n + 1%></h2>
<div class="stepcontainer">
<div class="steptext">
    <%= step.instruction %>
</div>
<div class="modalbutton">
    <%= render(step.flags.new) %>   
</div>


<% if step.input_contact.present? %>
    <div class="productimg">
        <div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">   
            <span class="i_contact i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.i_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-image-width="<%= step.i_connection.image.dimensions.first %>" data-index="<%= n %>"></span>   
            <%= link_to image_tag(step.i_connection.image.image.url(:medium), id: "iconnection#{n}" ), "#{step.i_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
            <div class="i_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>    
        </div>      
    </div>

    <% if step.i_connection.cord? && !step.o_connection.dongle? %>
        <div class="cableimg">
            <%= image_tag(step.i_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "orange")  %>
        </div>
    <% end %>           
<% end %>   <!-- end of step.input_contact.present -->

<% if step.o_connection.cord? && !step.o_connection.dongle? %>
    <div class="cableimg">
        <%= image_tag(step.o_connection.cord_type.image.url(:thumb), :class => "green") %>
    </div>      
<% end %>
<div class="productimg">
    <div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">
        <span class="o_contact o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= step.o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= step.o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= step.o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= step.o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-image-width="<%= step.o_connection.image.dimensions.first %>" data-index="<%= n %>"> </span>
        <%= link_to image_tag(step.o_connection.image.image.url(:medium), id: "oconnection#{n}"), "#{step.o_connection.image.image.url(:large)}", class: "fancybox" %>
        <div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
    </div>  
</div>              
</div>
```

Comment: Are you aware that the line of jQuery which is setting the width is  setting the width of the *span* element, not the image element.

Comment: I was not aware of that... do you have any suggestions on how I would pass it to the image element?

Comment: I don't know anything about Ruby, but since no one else is leaping to your aid, I'll say this: it looks like your image is a sibling of the span, that is, the image lives within the same div and comes after the span. If that's what is really going on, then in your js, where you say `$(this).css({ "width":newWidth })` you should instead say `$(this).next().css({ "width":newWidth })`. In other words, you want to set the css of the next sibling after the span, not the span itself. See [jQuery `.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jQuery, the .each is referring to the span, therefore inside of the `.each` you would need to traverse the DOM to access the image.

Since it appears that the image is the immediate sibling after the span, `.next` seems appropriate (although there are many other methods that could be used):

```
$('span.i_contact').each(function() {    
    var imgWidth = parseInt($(this).data('image-width'));    
    console.log(imgWidth);
    if (imgWidth < 600) {
    var newWidth = ((imgWidth / 600) * 300)  
    alert(newWidth);
    $(this).next().css({
        "width":newWidth
    })    
}   
...
```